# Alinear tres cajas css

Tags: html, css

Necesito que las cajas me queden proporcionalmente centradas dentro del footer y no logro que la última caja de redes me quede a la misma altura que las otras pero alineada a la derecha

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Necesito que las cajas me queden proporcionalmente centradas dentro del footer y no logro que la última caja de redes me quede a la misma altura que las otras pero alineada a la derecha

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

```css
.footergeneral{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
 }

.footers{
    background-color: aquamarine;
    width: 30%;
    height: 270px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;    
}

.footercontacto{
    float: left;
}

.footermapa{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.footerredes{
    position: static ;
    margin-top: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footergeneral">
            <div class="footers footercontacto">
                <h2>Contacto</h2>
                <p>Dirección: Av. nsndma 73767</p>
                <p>Teléfono: 2205 5807</p>
                <p>Email: mailto:jdhkaj@jhsadkj.com.uy</p>
                <p>Horario: Lunes a Viernes de 9 a 20
                            Sabados 9 a 20
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="footers footermapa">
                <h2>Mapa</h2>
                <p>Dirección: Av. nsndma 73767</p>
                <p>Teléfono: 2205 5807</p>
                <p>Email: mailto:jdhkaj@jhsadkj.com.uy</p>
                <p>Horario: Lunes a Viernes de 9 a 20
                            Sabados 9 a 20
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="footers footerredes">
                <h2>Mapa</h2>
                <p>Dirección: Av. nsndma 73767</p>
                <p>Teléfono: 2205 5807</p>
                <p>Email: mailto:jdhkaj@jhsadkj.com.uy</p>
                <p>Horario: Lunes a Viernes de 9 a 20
                            Sabados 9 a 20
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo de manera mas efectiva con la implementación de *FlexBox*, realizando lo siguiente:

- Al elemento contenedor de tus 3 secciones que sería la etiqueta `footer` dale una disposición de tipo `flex`
- El paso anterior ubicará los elementos sobre el eje principal o *main axis*
- Para lograr disponer los elementos con una distribución personalizada, podrás modificar la propiedad `justify-content` también del contenedor con alguna de las siguientes opciones:

  - `center`
  - `space-between`
  - `space-around`
  - `end`
  - `start` **(esta es la opción de distribución que ya tiene por defecto)**

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <style>
      :root {
        --color-fuente: #fff;
      }
      .footergeneral {
        background-color: crimson;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 auto;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 600px;
      }
      .elemento1 {
        color: var(--color-fuente);
      }
    </style>
    <div class="footergeneral">
      <div class="elemento1">
        <p>
          hola Mundo 1
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="elemento1">
        <p>
          Hola mundo 2
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="elemento1">
        <p>
          Hola Mundo 3
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Y con una salida así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Referencia**

- [Especificación sobre FlexBox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model)

Comment: Gracias amigo !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para alinear proporcionalmente bloques de contenido como tienes en tu `html` haciendo lo siguiente:

- Sin bootstrap

Colocando en `.footergeneral` un grid se haría la alineación de forma sencilla ya que tienes cada bloque bien estructurado dentro de los `div`. En el CSS:

```css
.footergeneral{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%;
}
```

- Con bootstrap

Tal y como se detalla en [la documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) puedes hacer la clase `footergeneral` como row y los bloques como col para que funcionara. Para una mejor praxis, es mejor crear un div padre que englobe a todos los bloques y no modificar todo el footer.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <footer class="footergeneral">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="footers footercontacto col">
                    <h2>Contacto</h2>
                    <p>Dirección: Av. nsndma 73767</p>
                    <p>Teléfono: 2205 5807</p>
                    <p>Email: mailto:jdhkaj@jhsadkj.com.uy</p>
                    <p>Horario: Lunes a Viernes de 9 a 20
                                Sabados 9 a 20
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="footers footermapa col">
                    <h2>Mapa</h2>
                    <p>Dirección: Av. nsndma 73767</p>
                    <p>Teléfono: 2205 5807</p>
                    <p>Email: mailto:jdhkaj@jhsadkj.com.uy</p>
                    <p>Horario: Lunes a Viernes de 9 a 20
                                Sabados 9 a 20
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="footers footerredes col">
                    <h2>Mapa</h2>
                    <p>Dirección: Av. nsndma 73767</p>
                    <p>Teléfono: 2205 5807</p>
                    <p>Email: mailto:jdhkaj@jhsadkj.com.uy</p>
                    <p>Horario: Lunes a Viernes de 9 a 20
                                Sabados 9 a 20
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
```